# What's the best way to get UITextField selection changed notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitextfield

Using the notification center, as described in [How can I get a textDidChange (like for a UISearchBar) method for a UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919413/how-can-i-get-a-textdidchange-like-for-a-uisearchbar-method-for-a-uitextfield), allows you to get a notification when text in an iOS UITextField changes. I didn't see a similar notification for selection changes. What's the best way to detect and respond to changes in the selection for a UITextField?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Wire up a method using target/action to the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` control event on your instance of `UITextField`. This can be done in the interface builder or in code by adding a target/action pair to the text field and then implementing the specified method.

```
[self.textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldTextChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

`UITextField` also declares a `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol with methods that you can implement in your class to be notified of changes to an instance of `UITextField`. I recommend that you become comfortable with delegation as it is a common pattern in the Cocoa framework.

[UITextFieldDelegate Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Comment: [`UIControlEventEditingChanged`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlEventEditingChanged) only refers to text edits. I.e., the action only fires when the text changes while the text field `isEditing`. This doesn't include selection changes.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/uitextfield-monitoring-selectedrange/) has one solution without messing with private apis:

In short: Subclass UITextField, implement

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```

and check if the selection range has changed. But this does not notify about taps.

So what I did is after subclassing, observe the `selectedTextRange` property:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedTextRange" options:0 context:nil];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    [self notifyDelegateIfNecessary];
}
```

Works very well in iOS8.

Comment: why you don't override [UITextField setSelectedTextRange:(UITextRange *)selectedTextRange] if you anyway did subclass UITextField? Then all changes come along in this place.

Comment: @Leo 1. I do not want to change the behavior, only get notifications 2. I just checked in PlayGround and I think you cannot override that function.

Comment: It works for me (IOS 8+9). This way I surround the needs to remove the observer at the suitable place.

Comment: Your choice, I would not override a private method, but probably a thing of taste.

Comment: @Krisdigital if you override *setSelectedTextRange* and in its implementation call *[super setSelectedTextRange:text]*, you'll maintain the original behavior of the superclass but also get a notification point

Comment: @NAlexN I know, feel free to override to your liking ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way to detect selection in textField

add object property observer in viewDidAppear

```
  [self.keyboardInputFieldPassword addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedTextRange" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld  context:nil];
```

Then Add observe function for property

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"selectedTextRange"] && self.keyboardInputFieldPassword == object)
        [self textFieldDidChangeSelection:self.keyboardInputFieldPassword];
}
```

This will capture the selection range in UITextField

For following the convention, you should removeObserver in viewDidDisappear

```
[self.keyboardInputFieldPassword removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedTextRange" context:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
private func listenForSelection(in textField:UITextField) {
    textField.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedTextRange", options: [.new,.old], context: nil)
}
private func unlistenForSelection(in textField:UITextField) {
    textField.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedTextRange")
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    let textField = object as? UITextField
    assert(keyPath == "selectedTextRange")
    assert(textField != nil)
    // select everything but the first and last characters - just and example of the UITextInput API if you want to modify the selection
    if let startPosition = textField.position(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, offset: 1),
        let endPosition = textField.position(from: textField.endOfDocument, offset: -1) {
        let selectionRange = textField.textRange(from: startPosition, to: endPosition)
        textField.selectedTextRange = selectionRange
    }
}
```